# Is there a way to default the source of the HTML5 video?

Tags: javascript, html

I currently want to default the source of the video player to use the `webm` format. From my understanding of the video player, browsers play the first recognizable format they come across so I have the `webm` as the first source but it still uses the `mp4` format. Is there a way to set a default source for the browser?

```
<video controls>
  <source src="videofile.webm" />
  <source src="videofile.mp4" />
  <source src="videofile.ogv" />
</video>
```

Comment: Does it work if you **only** supply the WEBM source? And can you try adding the `type="video/webm"` or whatever type it should be to the source elements?  Also, what browser are you trying in?

Comment: Are you sure the browser you're testing on is able to support .webm? If your browser does not support .webm then it would skip to the next format that it supports, which could be .mp4

Comment: I'm currently using Chrome and the source looks like this `<source type="video/webm" src="url" />`. @zero298 Yes it works if I use just `webm`